# Updating Worksheet Headers Using VBA Macro?

Tags: excel, vba

Let me start with I'm not a programmer, I'm an accountant, so what I've come up with so far I learned from Googling my issue. I wrote a VBA Script to generate a custom header for each tab in an Excel document with detailed financial figures for my company's individual branch offices. However, the script is set to update the header upon save, and will only update the specific tab I'm working on instead of all tabs. I'd also like it to exclude certain tabs, but I cannot figure out how to get that to work.

Originally the VBA Script was setup to execute upon printing, but I thought changing it to upon save would update all tabs, but it has not.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As 
Boolean)
For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "&B&26" & 
ActiveSheet.Range("C21").Value & vbNewLine & ActiveSheet.Range("C22").Value 
& vbNewLine & ActiveSheet.Range("C23").Value & vbNewLine & 
ActiveSheet.Range("B24") & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("C20") & " " & 
ActiveSheet.Range("C9") & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("D9") & " " & 
ActiveSheet.Range("C10")
Next Worksheet
End Sub
```

I'd like to build into this macro to update all worksheet headers upon saving, or running, or whatever action needed so I don't have to open every tab and save for the headers to update.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use activesheet in a loop through other sheets.
Define WS as a worksheet variable to use in the loop.

you could also use an array variant to manually define each sheet.
Sheet1 as the code name or use the sheets name Sheets("Sheet1")

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Array1(0 To 3) As Variant

Array1(0) = Sheet2
Array1(1) = Sheet4
Array1(2) = Sheet1
Array1(3) = Sheet6

    For Each ws In Array1
        ws.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "&B&26" & _
            ws.Range("C21").Value & vbNewLine & ws.Range("C22").Value _
            & vbNewLine & ws.Range("C23").Value & vbNewLine & _
        ws.Range("B24") & " " & ws.Range("C20") & " " & _
        ws.Range("C9") & " " & ws.Range("D9") & " " & _
        ws.Range("C10")
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the assistance with this. However, I have 55 sheets that need updating, so all I did was modify your code above to include all of the sheet numbers, and I got the "For Each control variable on arrays must be Variant".